# Gradle Plugin that must load the compiled classes from the project

Tags: gradle

As part of writing a Gradle plugin for [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org), we stumbled upon a problem when dealing with Java migrations.

What is the best way to provide a Gradle plugin access on its classpath to the compiled classes of the project so that it can load and execute them?

Comment: You mean a task added by the plugin needs to execute the code of the project that the plugin was applied to?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't sure how to do this without using a JavaExec or ProcessBuilder in order to get the compiled classpath ([pull request](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/pull/13)).

Answer (score 3):

So the situation is that we have a plugin that adds a task that wants to execute code contained in the project that the plugin is applied to. In this case, the task (class) should have an input property of type `Iterable<File>` that gets configured (by the plugin) with the class path of the code to be executed (e.g. `sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath`). The task can then choose between the following ways to execute the code:

- The task uses `project.javaexec {}` to execute the code in a separate JVM. If the code isn't directly executable, the task may need to inject some bootstrap code onto the `javaexec` class path. A potential alternative to using `project.javaexec` is to use a `JavaExec` task in the first place.
- The task creates a new class loader, populates it with the class path, loads and instantiates the classes that serve as the entry point(s) to the API, and makes use of them as appropriate. If the task is written in Groovy, it can leverage duck typing, and no reflective code will be necessary beyond creating the entry points.

Comment: Thanks. Which would you recommend? I was also considering using the ant task instead of JavaExec, but they should be mostly equivalent code. Do you have an example of the second option, if that's your preferred?